# How do I get the value of the Value tag in an XML snippet?

Tags: xml, linq, linq-to-xml

Where is a good resource where I learn how to get values from XML via Linq?

Given the XML below returned from a web service, I need to figure out how to get the value in the Value tag, knowing that there could be multiple SubscriberFieldType tags.  In this instance, I only want the Value tag value that follows the Name tag with value of "DisplayName".

```
{<GetSubscriberFieldsResult>
  <Result>true</Result>
  <ResultCode>0</ResultCode>
  <Message />
  <Count>1</Count>
  <SubscriberFields>
    <SubscriberFieldType>
      <Name>DisplayName</Name>
      <Value>John Smith</Value>
    </SubscriberFieldType>
  </SubscriberFields>
</GetSubscriberFieldsResult>}
```

Answer (score 1):

This would return the value

```
var result = dox.Descendants().Where(n => n.Name == "Value").FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this seems to work, hopefully this is a good way to do it.

```
var displayName = subscriberFieldsResultXML.Root.Elements("SubscriberFields")
    .Descendants("SubscriberFieldType")
    .Where(i => (string)i.Element("Name") == "DisplayName")
    .Select(i => (string)i.Element("Value"))
    .FirstOrDefault();
```